# Delphi: format datetime without time part in midnight

Tags: datetime, delphi, time, format, repository

Delphi Seattle:

I want to format datetime field in a cxGridDBTableView (Devexpress, cxGrid) with this rule (as DateTimeToStr):

- Midnight - 00:00:00 - the time portion isn't visible
- Other times - the time portion is visible

As I remember the formatdatetime HH:NN:SS shows the time portion "everytime".

Do you know an option to simulate DateTimeToStr?
I want to use it in a repository.

Thank you!

Comment: Which grid do you use?

Comment: @DelphiCoder:  An answer shouldn't depend on which grid.  A future reader might be using a different one.

Comment: @MartynA: I agree. I just wanted to have more clarity.

Comment: TcxGrid (Devexpress), TcxGridDBTableView - and that repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "c" for the `DisplayFormat` of the field. The documentation states for that:

> The date using the format given by the ShortDateFormat global
>   variable, followed by the time using the format given by the
>   LongTimeFormat global variable. The time is not displayed if the
>   fractional part of the DateTime value is zero.

Comment: Note, this applies to `FormatDateTime()`, not to `DateTimeToStr()`

Comment: The question was about a field.That's why I mentioned the DisplayFormat property and the quote is directly from the corresponding docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.DB.TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to Remy Lebeau and Uwe Raabe, I made the following example:

```
function GridDateTime: string;
var
  dt: TDateTime;
  fs: TFormatSettings;
begin
  dt := Now;
  fs := TFormatSettings.Create;
  fs.LongTimeFormat := 'HH:NN:SS';
  result := DateTimeToStr(dt, fs);
end;
```

In the comments related to the other answer of @UweRaabe they were discussing about format string `'c'` and if it applies to `FormatDateTime()` or `DateTimeToStr()`.

The answer is: It applies to both!

Both functions internally call `DateTimeToString()`, which has a string parameter `Format`. With `FormatDateTime()` one can set it directly, but not with `DateTimeToString()`. There it is set empty. So what does `DateTimeToString()`, when `Format` is an empty string? It adds a 'C':

> if Format <> '' then AppendFormat(Pointer(Format)) else AppendFormat('C');

So it doens't matter if you use `'C'` as a format string or not.

**Note:** Based on Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo!

Comment: This is not a good approach. It is subject to locale representations, and it is just not very efficient in general. If you want to go this way, use this instead: `var dt: TDateTime; begin dt := Now; if TimeOf(dt) < EncodeTime(0,0,1,0) then grid[x, y] := DateToStr(dt) else grid[x, y] := DateTimeToStr(dt); end;`

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, I have misunderstood the question about the midnight part. The OP does not want the text "midnight" to apprear in his grid.

Comment: If this does not answer OP's question, then you should delete it by using the `delete` link beneath it.

Comment: @Jerry: Improving my anser at the moment

Comment: @MartynA: Only if OP is using some database components because of `DisplayFormat`. If my new answer is still not good, then I will delete it!